# Check if a file exist on remote server and save th url path in a magento attribute

Tags: magento

Hi im trying to check if a file exist on a remote server and then save the url path to the file in a attribute on the product in magento.

This is how far i have got . i use some code from another function i have that imports images to my magento store. But i have never tested to only get the url path .

```
    <?php

     ini_set('display_errors', 1);
     require_once('app/Mage.php');
     Mage::app();

     $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

     $url = "http://www.imonline.se/media42/trailers/199151abe/swinks/hkmedia/";
     foreach($_productCollection as $product)
        {
                //if(file_exists($serverurl))
                {
                    $thispro  =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
                    $attributeValue = $thispro->getFaktaId();
                    $imgupdate = $thispro->getImgupdate();

                 if($thispro->getFaktaId()=="" || $thispro->getImage()=="no_selection")
                 {
                    if($attributeValue != "")
                    {

                        copy($url.$attributeValue );

                        $im = $attributeValue.".mp4";
                        if(file_exists)
                            {
                            $product->setFilmUrl($url.$im);
                            $product->save();

                            }
                    }
                    }
                }
        }
```

?>

Comment: and when you test it, whats the result ?!?!?!

Comment: The script loops out all products without doing anything

Comment: have you debug this If conditions ? and see if its valid ?? or where the code exits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) - Checks whether a file or directory exists

To [Check if Remote File Exists using PHP](http://curiositybeyondcontrol.blogspot.com/2012/05/check-if-remote-file-exists-using-php.html)

```
$url = $url.$im;
$exist = file_exists_remote($url);
if($exist) {
 echo 'File Exists';
 $product->setFileUrl($url.$im);
 $product->save();
} else {
 echo 'File not found';
}
```

Comment: im getting this error when i trigger the script Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_exists_remote()